# Matrices diagonalizable and relation with eigenspace

Tags: math, matrix, linear-algebra

if 4-square Matrix A has 2 eigenvalues 3 and 0 and their eigenspace dimensions is 2 for both, is the matrix diagonalizable?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, since you can find 4 linearly independent eigenvectors in those two two-dimensional eigenspaces. Writing your matrix corresponding to the basis consisting of those 4 vectors would yield a diagonal matrix. But, I think this question is too specific to be asked in here. You can learn basic linear algebra from the books such as *Linear Algebra* by Serge Lang.

Comment: thank you, I just found that the sum of the dimension of eigenspaces  is equal to the size of the matrix

Comment: @someMan Actually that is not always the case. There are non-trivial matrices with no eigenspace at all. Consider pi/2 radians rotation in the plane.

Comment: well I am a beginner in linear algebra  and my major is cs I don't think we will go that deep in linear algebra in bachelors program

Comment: @FıratKıyak, that's not true, but you have to work in the complex numbers. In general, the the sum of the dimension of eigenspaces is equal to the number of Jordan blocs, which is at least 1.